# Does the total-immobility rule in Kamisado depend on only two immobile pieces, or on an unending sequence of immobile pieces?

Tags: kamisado

Does the total-immobility rule in Kamisado depend on only two immobile pieces, or on an unending sequence of immobile pieces?

For example, suppose Alice is playing Bob. Bob has just moved and landed on pink. Alice is thus supposed to move her pink piece, but it's immobile (blocked) and sitting on blue. Bob is thus supposed to move his blue piece. Suppose it, too, is immobile, but is sitting on brown. Does Alice move her brown piece, or is the game over?

(Sorry if my terminology is off. I've read the rules only in translation.)

Answer (score 1):

Taking the rules from [Yucata](https://www.yucata.de/en/Rules/Kamisado#Z8) as the link there to designers official page was broken.

> It is possible, although extremely unlikely, to get a situation where
> both players have towers which are completely blocked so that they
> cannot be moved, and for these towers to interact to form a ‘deadlock’
> situation where no further towers can be moved at all. In this
> situation, the player who made the last move prior to the occurrence
> of the deadlock situation (i.e. the player who ‘caused’ the deadlock)
> is considered to have lost the round, and their opponent is the winner
> of that round.

those rules also clarify your example where Alice and Bob keep repeating moves.

> They can involve a ‘perpetually repeating sequence’ of two dragon
> towers (one belonging to each player), or four towers, or six, or
> more.

So in your example Bob moved onto a pink square.  This caused the infinite loop so there for Bob lost and Alice won the round.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I read it differently from you. If, in my example, Alice wins, then there can't be a perpetually repeating sequence of four or more towers. Right?

Comment: just before the quoted part here, the linked rules say _"A player who finds that the tower they are supposed to be moving is completely blocked [...] Although the tower remains on the same spot, it is considered that this dragon tower has made a (zero-length) move that finished on this square."_ which to me implies that the sequence is tracked until a piece that can move is found, or it's determined that it's a loop (of two or more blocked pieces). So Alice would move their brown piece (or if it's blocked, it would again pass, etc.)